# Check which stylesheet is active and hide a div

Tags: jquery, css, conditional-statements

I currently have a theme that switches between 2 main stylesheets.

There is a single element integral to the design that cannot be changed stylistically with CSS, so I decided to toggle the visibility between 2 separate versions with the appropriate colors. (It's a tag cloud that is loaded via javascript; one version matches the first theme's colors and the other version matches the other theme's colors.) Here is the very simple code I added to make the panel switch:

```
$(function(){
    $('#pink').click(function(){
        $('#pinkcloud').show("fold");
        $('#greencloud').hide("fold");
     });
    $('#green').click(function(){
        $('#greencloud').show("fold");
        $('#pinkcloud').hide("fold");
    });
});
```

(#Green and #pink are IDs corresponding to the links to click to change the theme.)

The problem is, the theme operates on cookies, so it will remember what theme you chose. The divs obviously do not, so the default one loads automatically no matter *what* theme your browser remembers.

What do I add to my code to ensure that the browser checks which stylesheet is active and shows the proper div when it loads? How do I check, in my javascript, for which file it is currently reading?

I'm awful at explaining things sometimes, so here's the theme so you can actually see what I mean ([x](http://featherystylesheets.tumblr.com/)). To see the problem, click the green theme option, refresh the page, and look at the clippings section, which will be pink. You can click the green theme option again to show the properly colored section, but I'd obviously like the right one to show automatically.

The code for the theme switching can be located [here](http://2008.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/styleswitch/styleswitch.js), so you can see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are going to need to store some value in a cookie that can switch between the stylesheets, so that the information can be preserved.

So, my working might be rough and needs some testing, but firstly I would use a very good and light cookie plugin found [HERE](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Then you need some jquery along these lines:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
   $.cookie('cookieName', 'green', { path: '/', expires: 365}); // set as the default on the root document for 1 year. 
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#pink').click(function(){
      $.cookie('cookieName', 'pink', { path: '/', expires: 365}); // set on click
   });
   $('#green').click(function(){
      $.cookie('cookieName', 'green', { path: '/', expires: 365}); // reset to original
   });
});
```

Then I would add a stylesheet into the head of the document and give it an id.

```
<link id="cssToggle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yoursite.com/css/green-style.css" />
```

Then you need an if statement to toggle them.

```
if ($.cookie('cookieName') === 'green') {
   $('#cssToggle').attr('href','http://yoursite.com/css/green-style.css')
}else if($.cookie('cookieName') === 'pink'){
   $('#cssToggle').attr('href','http://yoursite.com/css/pink-style.css')
}
```

I may have completely over-egged this, and there could be more elegant solutions, but I believe this would work. I am going to try and test it.

EDIT: Crude example working here: http://jsfiddle.net/6eqs428v/

Comment: Quick question: why the stylesheet link? I have switching between themes already accounted for, you see. I simply want to take care of the visibility of 2 divs when the theme changes in this specific function, and for the displaying div to match the given theme. I believe you are definitely right when you say I need to make a new cookie, that will help for sure! I just want to clarify what I need in this instance, and your explanation seems to be going in the direction of toggling the css. Toggling the div visibility and saving which was last visible in a cookie is what I want.

Comment: Using part of your advice (and code), I tweaked my code and it now works! I just made the cookies on click and applied the hiding code in the conditional. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes I wrote it like that as the first line of your question states 'I currently have a theme that switches between 2 main stylesheets.' But it seems as though the code you are trying to implement is much simpler. But I am glad that it was of some help.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to run that code on page load as well as the click events. Your "#pinkcloud" element is the one showing by default so you will just have to change to the green style by adding something like this to your "switchStylestyle" function:

```
if(styleName==='green') { 
    $('#greencloud').show();
    $('#pinkcloud').hide(); 
}
```

Comment: I'll keep working at it, but I'm having problems properly adding the code. I still don't quite get the syntax of if else statements, but I'll get back to you once I fiddle some more!